# Excluding hyphen from regular expression character classes?

Tags: regex

To illustrate the subtle problem, here are some examples in JavaScript so you can test right in your browser:

```
/[2-5]+/.test('2')   // true, as expected.
/[2-5]+/.test('-')   // false, as expected.
/[2-5]+/.test('2-')  // true. WTF?!!!
```

Questions:

1. Is this a bug or a feature?
2. How do you exclude the hyphen when you test a character class?

## Update

This is a stupid question. My bad. Need to get some rest before coding again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
/^[2-5]+$/.test('2-')
```

This will make sure that there are only the numbers 2-5 from the front (^) to the end ($) of the string.

Comment: I'll be able to accept your answer in 5 minutes!